# Make a Hosted Repository a submodule of another Hosted Repository in Phabricator

Tags: git, repository, phabricator

How can I make a hosted repository a submodule of another hosted repository in `Phabricator`?

`Phabricator1` version latest (2015-12-09)
Repository Type: `Git`
`git` version 1.8.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is indifferent to where a repository is hosted as long as it has access.  You can use a repo hosted in Github, your Phabricator, or any other repository that is available to you. From the Git help when I type `git submodule add`, I get this:

`git core\git-submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]`

To Simplify:

`git submodule add [clone_url]`

Additional references: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules